# Why doesnt my javadocs index.html open when I send my file to colleague?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, javadoc

I have successfully created javadoc on my Java code base in Eclipse IDE. When I open index.html, it opens fine for me and displays correctly. I tried mailing it to a colleague, and they get an error message using 2 different browsers. What could be causing this? Do I need to export it differently from eclispe rather than just sending the attachment?

Comment: What error message?

Comment: What exactly did you mail to your colleague?  Just the index.html file?  What error message is your colleague seeing?

Comment: Just the index.html file. "This page cant be displayed" in both browsers. Works fine for me in both IE and chrome